# in Qt5.12 I am trying to get painted horizontal headers to size properly

Tags: qt, qheaderview

I have subclassed QHeaderView as a horizontal header and reimplemented its paintSection() method to allow adding a the text e.g. "Axis X1" to the header label. However, all attempts to automatically resize the horizontal headers so that the original text + painted in text fits within the header have failed.

The resizing appears to work fine when resizing to the header text but fails when adding content to the header as it appears that Qt's resizing algorithms do not account for painted-in content?
My code is below:

Please note in particular the void HHeaderView::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const
method below. The lines:

```
painter->save();
painter->drawText(rect,Qt::AlignCenter,"Axis X1 "+headertext);
painter->restore();
return;
```

add content i.e. "Axis X1" to the header label headertext. Unfortunately, Qt does not appear to account for the size of this extra content when resizing the columns to fit the content and the header content is clipped.

Comment: Probably the size of the original text is cached somewhere and/or your extra string is not considered. Why don't you modify the header text itself, from the model, for example?

Comment: Thanks for your response. While modifying the header text itself would seem like the most obvious solution, the header text is used elsewhere to make programmatic decisions and modifying it just for the display would complicate the whole application's design. I therefore wanted to keep the header text constant while making mods to indicate the state of a column, e.g.  that it was selected for plotting. I did come up with a solution, i.e. to use Qt to find the full header width (with mod) and then to manually set the column's width. But I don't know if this is the "idiomatic" Qt way.

Comment: And my solution is: